# What is the correct way to import or open the Android Source Code into Eclipse or Android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-source

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've taken last source code of Android by following the instructions from the official website of Android: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.

I also followed the instructions for installing other programs that are required for build Android source code: http://source.android.com/source/building.html.

To build the Android source code I follow instructions from http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html.

Build has not been done successfully without installing some additional programs that I have taken through the forums by asking why not Android source code build successfully.

After build successfully image is created in `out/target/produkt/generic/system.img`, then I opened the emulator by written the command "emulator" in terminal.

My question is what is the correct way to import or open the Android source code into Eclipse or Android Studio to start working, because when I import projects of Android source code in Eclipse. I have errors with this ways:

1. Create an empty java project. Properties>Java Build Path>Source>Link Source>Android folder path.
2. File>new>java project> Location: Android folder path.
3. Import>Android>Existing Android Code into Workspace>Root Directory: Android Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get aosp build work from a terminal window. I work on aosp 4.0.3 fork. Ubuntu 10.04 is preferred for this. It is old, but you don't have to change AOSP files to build.
Building aosp from eclipse is not an option as far as I know.

Please check [Using eclipse to browse/edit/debug aosp tutorial](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/using-eclipse-to-browse-and-edit-aosp.html).

Comment: Thank a lot for the help, for the moment I modify source code manually by gedit application and build it from the terminal window. To add projects applications in aosp I follow this link:[How to add App in Android as Basic App](http://baharkhan.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/how-to-add-own-app-in-source-android/)

Answer (score 0):

file>new>Project...>Android Project from existing code.

Comment: I tried this way but most of the projects have errors in eclipse, for the more you can see a photo. Most of the projects have errors because use a package which is not found within the project.
[photo1](http://lamirshkurti.com/Error1.png)
[photo2](http://lamirshkurti.com/Error2.png)